# Quicktime X + AVI = no sound

Tags: macos, audio, codec, avi, quicktime

i got an avi container file and want to play with QT X. I installed [Perian](http://www.perian.org/) but sound does not work for a few files.
I used MediaInfo(http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net) to determine the used audio codec in this file. According to MediaInfo it's: 
*74.2 Kbps, 48.0 KHz, 2 channels MPEG Audio (MP3) (Version1)(Layer3)(Joint stereo / MS Stereo)*

Other *.mp3 files work properly. Audio-Video-Setup was set to 41KHz and 48KHz... none works.
In QT X -> Show Information i get this:

*Generic MPEG-4, 640 x 272, Unknown
MPEG Layer 3, Stereo, 48,000 kHz*

Any idea? Thank you!

I don't want to use VLC Media Player and i don't want to convert the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it. I deleted my messy folder (approx 170 files) and copied the folder (approx 20 files) from a clean SL installation + perian. Now it works =)

Comment: What messy folder?

Comment: My /Library/QuickTime